# update single state value in deeply nested object

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Looking to update a single value in a deeply nested state. Not sure how to update deeply nested state due to complexity. I have been able to hit the object within' the array, but don't exactly know how to update the state for that value.

I know redux-toolkit uses immer, so I don't *think* I have to spread my states, but not 100% sure.

```
const initialState = {
   first: {
     1: {},
      2: [
            aa: {
               a: '',
               z: '',
               d: ['dance', 'door', 'drill'],
            },
            bb: {
               ...
            }  
         ]
   },
   second: [],
   third: {}
}

const mySlice = createSlice({
   name: 'mySlice',
   initialState,
   reducers:
      getObjA(state, action) {
          const objA = state.first.1.2.aa.find(obj => obj.a); //Can get to object here.
          objA = action.payload; //does not update the object
      }
});

export const {getObjA} = mySlice.actions;
export default mySlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, redux toolkit lets you mutate the state object. also, you can't a change a `const` after declaration.

I suggest you use `findIndex` and `splice`:

```
const objAIndex = state.first.1.2.findIndex(obj => obj.a);
state.first.1.2.splice(objAIndex,1,action.payload)
```